# Is 2-sylow subgroup of a rational group also a rational group?

Tags: characters, gr.group-theory

As we know, a finite group $G$ is a rational group if $\chi (g)\in\mathbb{Q}$, where $\chi$ is every irreducible charahter and $g\in G$. I have an interesting question that is "Is 2-Sylow subgroup of a rational group also a rational group?"

Any hints will be appreciated :)

Comment: The answer seems to be no.   Keep in mind that symmetric groups are rational groups, so that's the first case to investigate
starting with `$S_4$` and its `$2$`-Sylow subgroups.   

Comment: @Jim: The Sylow 2-subgroups of the symmetric groups are iterated wreath products, and these are rational groups.

Comment: Yes, that sounds familiar now that you mention it.    But I still wonder whether the questioner has begun by looking at cases where the given group is rational.   In any case, Geoff's answer is quite useful.

Comment: An almost-simple rational group has rational Sylow 2-subgroups by Feit–Seitz and a quick check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This had been a long standing conjecture, but it has now been answered negatively.  Isaacs and Navarro have found a counterexample.

Comment: @Mark Lewis: Thanks Mark for the comment. May I ask you to inform me the related paper? :-) 

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to reply.  I don't think the paper of Isaacs and Navarro has appeared any where yet.  (I have a copy of the preprint.)  I will try to post a link when it does appear.

Comment: The paper is online, but not in print yet, I think: http://www.springerlink.com/content/e6428q435750326l/

Answer (score 14):

This is a fairly long-standing question in certain quarters, though I would need to check who was the first to ask it (if such a person is well-defined). Isaacs and Karagueuzian answered a somewhat related question in the negative (around 2002), disproving a conjecture of Kirillov. They proved that a Sylow $2$-subgroup of ${\rm GL}(13,2)$ is not a real group. (Recall that the definition of a real group is analagous to the definition of a rational group given in the question. A finite group is real if and only if all its complex irreducible characters are real-valued, which is equivalent to all its elements being conjugate to their inverses). However, I should point out that in my original post, I had mis-remembered the content of the Isaacs-Karagueuzian result. Contrary to my earlier statement, the group ${\rm GL}(13,2)$ is not itself a real group. For example, it contains an element of order $127$ which is not conjugate to its inverse. As  far as I am aware, the given question about rational groups is open. One of the difficulties with the question is that rational groups are relatively rare (a loose statement, I know, but justifiable).

Comment: @Geoff: @Jim: I point out that, we know some properties about rational group , for example every quotient of a rational group is rational group and Sylow 2-subgroup of symmetric groups are rational group. Also, we know that the question is a conjecture and is a very hard problem. W. Feit said that, "Probably this problem is wrong but still there is not counterexample for it". 

Comment: Yes, what you say is not inconsistent with what I said, I think.
The composition factors of rational finite groups are almost
completely understood ( see the MR review by A. Turull of the 2005 
Proc LMS paper by P. Hegedus, for example). I almost agree with Feit, except that I could not predict that the conjecture is wrong:
nevertheless, rational groups are few and far between, and it is difficult to make uniform statements about them, as their structure varies considerably.

Comment: Regarding Feit's statement, I just mean that I would not go as far.
Until the conjecture is proved or disproved, I would feel unable to 
say that it is probably wrong-it may well be, but I don't know
and can't say.

Comment: @Geoff:Thanks for sharing thoughts. :)